# JAXB unmarshalling converts CR-LF to LF?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Apparently unmarshalling of XML elements which contain CR-LF (Windows style end-of-lines) leads to String fields which contain LF instead. The CR seems to be dropped.

I am not sure whether this happens within JAXB or within the XML parsing.

Is this behaviour configurable, and if so, where and how?